# Kissing a child in the Ezras Nashim

Tags: halacha, women, synagogue, kissing

It says in the Rema in OC Siman 98 Sif 1 that it's ossur to kiss a child in shul. There are perhaps exceptions to this rule and cases where it would be allowed however that's that it says in the Rema (See [here](http://hirhurim.blogspot.co.il/2010/06/kissing-children-in-shul.html) for many details in this halacha.)

Under the normal circumstances where it's ossur, would it also be ossur in the Ezras Nashim (i.e. for a woman to kiss a child in that part of the shul)?

Comment: Ezras Nashim is the shul one can daven there btzibur siman 55

Comment: I have been told by an OR that since this law occurs in Hilchos Tefillo and not in Hilchos Beis Haknesses, it should be allowed to kiss a child **not** at the time of prayer.

Comment: @sam http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%94#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A0.D7.94_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.9B

Comment: @doubleAA ,Mishna Brurah נב) מצטרף עמהם - דאף דיש הפסק מחיצה ביניהם כיון דמראה להם פניו דומה למה שמבואר לקמן בסימן קצ"ה לענין זימון דאם מקצתן רואין אלו את אלו דמצטרפין וא"כ לפ"ז פשוט העומדים בעזרת נשים ובמחיצה המפסקת יש חלון ומראה להם פניו משם מצטרף עמהם לעשרה וכ"ש דאם יש בלעדו עשרה נחשב תפלה בצבור עי"ז ואעפ"כ יותר טוב אם בנקל הוא לו לירד לבהכ"נ שירד דיש מהאחרונים שחולקין על עיקר הדין וסוברין דענינינו אינו דומה כלל לזימון

Comment: @sam OK so Aruch Hashulchan vs Mishna Berura.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38488

Comment: related: http://hirhurim.blogspot.co.il/2010/06/kissing-children-in-shul.html

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok- this idea has been said in the name of reb Moshe Feinstein along with people having witnessed him kiss children in shul not during tefila. I have personally seen his son Reb Dovid do the same.

Comment: An ezras ashim is still part of the bais hakineses, even though woman daven there. You should know that in shulchan aruch there are many laws regarding a bais hakeneses for example, not to be light headed, and not to eat there. I'm wondering why you asked just about kissing in a bais hakeneses and not about all the other laws of a bais hakeneses.

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok The idea you mentioned is found in Meged Givas Olam pg 92

Comment: see here Ben Ish Chai : אות יא
אסור לשחוט בבית הכנסת גם לתורך כפרות, וכן בעזרת נשים שמתפללין שם נמי אסור ...

Answer (score 2):

R' Avraham Yosef (son of the late R' Ovadia Yosef) was asked this question.

He [replied](http://www.moreshet.co.il/WEB/shut/shut2.asp?id=152680) that there's no difference, and that the Ezras Nashim counts as the Shul and thus forbidden.

> ?האם מותר לתת נשיקה לחברה בבית הכנסת בעזרת נשים, כשאין ספר תורה בחוץ
>
> בביהכ''נ לא מנשקים כדי להראות שאין חיבה כחיבת הקב''ה

Answer (score 1):

In the country I come from, to kiss anyone or anything in the shul besides the Torah was forbidden. In the shul, we are in the presence of the Shechinah. After the Shechinah, no one and nothing is holier than His Torah. Therefore, not to disrespect Hashem's presence and not to insult the Torah, we were not allowed to kiss anyone or anything in the shul besides the Torah. Jews of former Soviet Georgia have been observing this tradition over 24 centuries.

Comment: I'm not sure about the historicity of the final statement, but thank you for your input. Can you provide a source that specifically addresses the question as to whether one may kiss a child *in the women's section* of the Shul?

Comment: @tamar this law is written in the Shulchan Aruch

Comment: What about sefarim when being put away or after being dropped?